# MySQL - Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql

I can't insert any rows into my database, and the error I'm getting is:

This doesn't make any sense as it was working fine before, nothing has changed as far as I know. The ID field is set to primary, not null and auto increment:
[image]

I was able to insert a row manually through PHPMyAdmin. Heres the code I'm inserting with:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO wp_genomics_results (file_id,snp_id,genotype,reputation,zygosity) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

    $stmt = $ngdb->prepare($query);

    $file_id = $this->fileID;
    $snp_id = $row['id'];
    $genotype = $this->formatGenotype($extractedGenotype);
    $zygosity = $this->assignZygosity($genotype,$minor_allele);
    $reputation = $this->assignReputation($zygosity,$genotypes);

    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $file_id,$snp_id,$genotype,$reputation,$zygosity);
    $stmt->execute();
```

I tried deleting the table and creating a new table but it didn't fix it. Is there anything else I can do to try and diagnose and fix this?

Comment: what value is `$snp_id = $row['id']`

Comment: also your types don't match in `$stmt->bind_param("sssss",`

Answer (score 0):

make sure for this line:

> $stmt->bind_param("sssss",
>   $file_id,$snp_id,$genotype,$reputation,$zygosity);

First parameter of bind_param() you used is "sssss" that means all off data is string. Please fix it as the right type data of your type on table database.
Please use "i" for integer. For example:

> $stmt->bind_param("iisss",
>   $file_id,$snp_id,$genotype,$reputation,$zygosity);

I make the code above as an example because I can not see all of your table descibe.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

The table definition looks really strange. It looks like there's a second index on the `id` column. The `id` column is already defined as the `PRIMARY KEY`.
It's this line in the table definition that is bothers me...

```
  KEY `id` (`id`)
```

It's bizarre that MySQL would even let you *add* a second index on the same column, and not return an error like "such an index already exist" or "the set of columns is already indexed" or such.

I recommend you run a statement to drop the index named `id`. Execute either

```
  DROP INDEX `id` ON `wp_genomics_results`;
```

-or-

```
  ALTER TABLE `wp_genomics_results` DROP KEY `id`;
```

It's possible that this index was contributing to the issue.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I suggest you figure out *exactly* which statement is throwing an error.

I suspect it's *not* the execution of `INSERT INTO wp_genomics_results` statement.

If it were me, I'd take a look at the `assignZygosity` and `assignReputation` functions. I suspect the culprit is in down in there.

I suspect there's something going on in those functions. My guess (just a guess) is that one of those functions is performing a lookup to get a value for a foreign key. And, if a foreign key value isn't found, something is being executed to INSERT a row into the referenced table. There must be *some* reason that function is being called, some reason we're not just using the value supplied as a parameter...

The `formatGenotype` function is also a suspect, by proximity. (I'm less a-feared of that function name... but again, I have no idea what that function is doing.)

If that's not the issue, if it's really the execution of the INSERT statement shown in the code, then I'd look for a "BEFORE INSERT" trigger on the `wp_genomics_results` table... maybe the trigger is performing an insert to some other table.

---

As a quick test, I'd comment out the calls to those functions, and just assign a literal values to `$zygosity` and `$reputation`.

I want to know the *exact* line number in the *exact* file where the error is being thrown.

I also want the *complete* error message from MySQL.

Following *every* execution of a database interaction, I want to check the return, and if there's an error, I want (for debugging purposes) a unique message that indicates where we are in the code when the error is thrown, along with the *complete* error message returned from MySQL (`mysqli_error`).

I'm not going to just assume, without evidence, that it's the execution of *this* particular statement that's causing the error.

And if it really is this statement, then we'd need to take a look at the actual MySQL definition of the table... the output from a `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_genomics_results` statement.

And we want to make sure that we are looking at the *same* MySQL instance and database that the code is connecting to, and not some other MySQL instance or database.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I commented out $reputation, $genotype and $zygosity but it doesn't change anything. None of the fields are connected to any foreign keys. I tried inserting with this instead (I'll post it in an answer)

Answer (score 0):

I tried inserting with the WordPress database connection:

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_genomics_results (file_id,snp_id,genotype,reputation,zygosity) VALUES ('$file_id','$snp_id','$genotype','$reputation','$zygosity')");
```

and it works, but if I try using an identical query with my own database connection:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', NG_DB_USER, NG_DB_PASS, NG_DB_NAME);
$db->query("INSERT INTO wp_genomics_results (file_id,snp_id,genotype,reputation,zygosity) VALUES ('111','$snp_id','$genotype','$reputation','$zygosity')");
```

I get the same error:

> Error No: 1364 - MySQL error Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

I don't understand why it works with wordpress but not my own database connection. I went into my mysql.ini file and changed this:

> sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,
>   NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"

to this:

> sql-mode=""

and now I can insert a row, the error stopped happening. I still don't understand why this error was occuring to begin with. And now theres a new error happening:

> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

I don't understand it because the id column is set to auto increment. Theres also no rows in there with ID = 0. I even emptied the table to make absolute sure there is no row in there with ID = 0. I'm very confused about whats happening. Heres the output of the table structure:

```
> mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_genomics_results;

| wp_genomics_results | CREATE TABLE `wp_genomics_results` (
   `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `snp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `genotype` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
   `reputation` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
   `zygosity` int(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I notice it says 1 row in set, but the table is actually empty. And once again, I'm able to insert a new row through PHPMyAdmin:
[image]

Comment: I added an EDIT to my answer. SHOW CREATE TABLE is showing a (bizarre) secondary index on the `id` column. Try getting rid of that unnecessary index: `DROP INDEX \`id\` FROM \`wp_genomics_results\``.  (Note: the "1 row in set" message is referring to the resultset returned by the SHOW CREATE TABLE statement. It's in now way related to the number of rows in the wp_genomics_results table.)

Comment: 1 row in set: It means the result of your SHOW TABLE. It is not the count of your records in the table. KEY `id` (`id`) is redundant, you do not need it. Write an INSERT query without PHP first (for direct use in PHPMySQL's query window), and then convert it into PHP/Bind-Params.

Answer (score 0):

Oh God I feel like an idiot. All this time, the problem was that I had the wrong database selected. So it was querying a table from a different database, and this tables ID field didn't have auto increment set. Ah well, it was a good learning experience, getting to know MySQL better.